# Django Gunicorn no module named error

Tags: django, gunicorn

My project directory structure looks like following:

[image]

My wsgi file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and my manage.py file:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

in my settings .py I have:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'
```

I added my project path to python with following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ec2-user/amm_inovision_backend:$PYTHONPATH
```

and I am trying to run gunicorn command where my manage.py file is as: `gunicorn amm_inovision_backend.config.wsgi:application`

But it throws me error no module named amm_inovision_backend.config.wsgi

If I run instead `gunicorn config.wsgi:application` it throws no module named amm_inovision_backend.config.settings

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: in the screenshot it is amm_ino_backend but actually it is amm_inovision_backend in the production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to use gunicorn you must run gunicorn installed on your virtual environment.
so you don't need to export any python path, you only need to find path to gunicorn on your virtual-env where Django is installed, or you can add path to virtual environment not to project files.
also you need first to edit your `wsgi.py`
you have to replace this 
`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")` with 
`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")`

your command must be something like that:
`/path/to/.virtual-envs/your-env/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application`

Comment: Well I am using virtual env on my local but I haven't created one in production, I have simply cloned the repo and did pip install from requirements.txt and my app basically started. Could that be a problem?

Comment: it's better to use virtual env even if you are on production to avoid any conflict issue, but any way you can go without virtual env, but you don't need `export PYTHONPATH` please remove it and run `gunicorn config.wsgi:application`

Comment: @Nitish isn't this answer like the answer you marked !,
I replied to you after few minutes not after a day, what's your point of view ?

Comment: Thank you @Nitish

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

note the "CONFIG.SETTINGS"